# Is there any option to set in Visual Studio 2008 that would turn off the Silverlight XAML preview by default?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, silverlight

The preview for a silverlight usercontrol in vs2008 is mostly useless to me and it takes forever to load.  I spend a lot of time switching to XAML only and minimizing the preview for every Silverlight UserControl that I open.  Is there a setting whereby I can tell VS2008 to by default open these in XAML-only mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that when I use the option "Open With" I experienced lockups and it was a problem.  (Probably just me.)
In any case, this option works much better for me: Use Visual Studio Tools menu, Select Options -- Text Editor -- XAML -- Miscellaneous. And then you will see "Always Open documents in full XAML view"  That's the ticket.

Saves so much time.

Comment: This is a great answer too!  Actually more closely aligned with what I was looking for.  I too have been experiencing some lock-ups but I never thought to attribute it to the Open With solution.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Right-click and choose "Open with..."

Choose "Source Code (Text) Editor" so you get intelisense and set it to default from that dialog.

Poof.  No more designer :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Add to it that I can set this as the default. Also note that you should choose "Source Code (Text)" NOT "XML Editor" as with the Source Code option you retain IntelliSense.

Comment: +1 for enhancing the accepted answer with further helpful info

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way of opening XAML only.  But you can certainly open with only the XML editor enabled.

- Right Click
- Select Open With ...
- Choose "XML Editor"

Comment: You want to choose "Source Code (Text)" to retain IntelliSense on the XAML.